# parameter.value.getTime is not a function while saving date to database

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, angular, datetime

I am saving the date to SQL database from nodejs. While saving the date to SQL I am getting error " parameter.value.getTime ".

While passing a date in this format while passing it to SQL.

```
2018-06-27T18:30:00.000Z
```

In early records in the database, DateTime format is this one.

```
2018-05-25 14:39:19.433
```

How can I solve this error? I already used moment js to use another format for saving the date but it is not working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should not try to change the format of your `String`, but convert it into JavaScript `Date` instead:

```
var yourDate = new Date(yourString);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer i tried it in node js. and it worked finally.

Comment: But it saves one day lesser than real date. Any solution ??

Comment: which DBMS are you using ?

Comment: SQL server 2014

Comment: Try changing the data type to datetime2 (not SQL Server expert though)

Comment: If that doesn't work, I'm afraid it's a SQL Server related issue and if so I cannot help

Comment: @Aarsh its probably saving it in utc time